# How to open a QNetworkSession to a WiFi AP specifying which physical interface to use?

Tags: qt, qt5

My computer has 2 wlan interfaces: One integrated ("Wi-Fi") and an external adapter ("Wi-Fi 2"). How can I make my Qt application establish a connection to a given access point (AP) through the second interface?

I want to make sure that the first interface is always used to connect to the internet (my ISP router), while the second interface is used to connect to a third-party device (which is a Wi-Fi AP itself).

The following code connects to an AP (SSID = DeviceRouter). But I don't know how to force using my secondary interface (Wi-Fi 2).

```
// My target SSID and interface (let's assume this is an open AP)
QString ssid = "DeviceRouter";
QString interface = "Wi-Fi 2";  // I want to use my secondary interface

// Get all configurations
QNetworkConfigurationManager mgr;
mgr.updateConfigurations();
waitForSignal( &mgr, SIGNAL( updateCompleted() ), 20000 ); // implemented elsewhere
QList<QNetworkConfiguration> allConfigs = mgr.allConfigurations();

// Select the configuration matching my target SSID
bool connected = false;
foreach( QNetworkConfiguration config, allConfigs ) {
    if( config.name() == ssid && config.bearerType == QNetworkConfiguration::BearerWLAN ) {
        QNetworkSession s( config );
        // How can I set the interface for the session?
        s.open();
        connected = w.waitForOpened( 30000 );
        if( connected ) {
            qDebug() << "You're connected on interface: " << s.interface().humanReadableName();
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

So, output is always `You're connected on interface: Wi-Fi 2`.

Comment: What's `w` in `w.waitForOpened`? Its definition is missing in your code sample

Comment: @MartinHennings Sorry, this is a typo. It should be `s` (`s.waitForOpened( 30000 ); ` ).

Comment: @Samuel i think that you should describe a little bit more your network topology, usually it's the routing system of your OS that chooses which interface is to be used to reach a particular destination address. If by chance (and that is a peculiar setup) both your interfaces can reach your destination then with QSockets you can use a setsockopt on the underlying socke descriptor to force the binding address and thus the interface to use. I have never faced the problem with QNetworkAccessManager though.